# Windows 7 on D830 -> mouse way too slow!

Tags: windows-7

Even on max pointer speed, the mouse speed on the D830's trackpad is absurdly slow. With Windows XP, I was fine. What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Dell drivers. They should work with Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell drivers did not solve the issue in my case even though having basic Dell optical mouse. I installed Logitech SetPoint and was able to get it way faster than the fastest on Windows7

Comment: Logitech SetPoint made my mouse movement even slower.